# Non-zero exit code (1) Python PyCharm

Tags: mysql, python, pycharm

Estoy instalando el Modulo de `MySQLdb` desde el `PyCharm` y me arroja el error `Non-zero exit code (1)`. Alguien sabe como puedo arreglarlo? Tengo que actualizar la versión del `PIP`?

Comment: ¿Que version de python3 o python2 estas usando?

Comment: Estoy usando python 3

Comment: Prueba instalarlo directamente con pip, ¿Que version de python3 tienes?

Comment: Tengo el 3.4, intentaré a ver como me va, le aviso

Comment: Collecting Mysqldb

  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement Mysqldb (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for Mysqldb

Comment: Segun veo comentarios en SO en inglés, no hay soporte para esa libreria para python3, en este post dan varias opciones: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4960048/python-3-and-mysql , revisalo.

Comment: Alguna otra libreria de Python que conecte a mysql?

Comment: Prueba con mysql-connector-python

Comment: Desde el cmd puede utilizar el MySQLdb, con la version de Python 3.4. Pero si intento usarlo desde el Pycharm me produce el error.

Comment: Esta seguro que es el mismo python. ¿No habras instalado otro python?

Comment: Si, es el mismo python el que uso a traves de Pycharm

Comment: Me parece extraño, si es asi ve a pycharm y en la misma parte que indicas el python hay una lista de paquetes, en ese lugar deberias encontrar a ese modulo.